# Exploding string using multiple criterias in PHP

Tags: php, explode

I need to parse data from a string the string looks like:

`id|0;f|Luke;l|skywalker;email|some@one.com;`(etc...)

I would like to convert this to something like:

```
$t = array(
 'id' => 0,
 'f' => 'Luke',
 'l' => 'Skywalker',
 'email' => 'some@one.com',
 //....
)
```

Now i know I can explode then for loop then explode again but is there a shortcut to this?

Like 1 line of 1 function in PHP that will do this?

Tkx

Comment: No, there is not a function in PHP called `automatically_parse_my_string_kthx()`.  You're going to have to settle for something that isn't a single function call.

Comment: Like is said in my question: "Now i know I can explode then for loop then explode again". I am looking for something less painful to execute or a quicker way

Comment: @lasers: "something less painful" --- what could be less painful than 5 lines of trivial code? Oneliner that doesn't fit the screen width?

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this. Call explode to split it on `;`, loop over that, explode to split it on `|`, push them into the array.

Comment: @zerkms well its explode then for loop then explore again, its not that painful but 1 function call will be faster i guess

Comment: @lasers: it would be faster if it did it in other way, not because it's wrapped in a function

Comment: haha so funny when you see who had NO solutions for this and close the question and then a very good solution was proposed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This little snippet should take care of it in most cases:

```
parse_str(strtr($data, '|;', '=&'), $t);
```

It turns the string into something that looks like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and then parses it according to those rules.

Note that certain characters will get a different meaning such as `%20` will be turned into spaces, etc.

Comment: /me goes to register a second account to be able to upvote this awesomeness twice

Comment: @zerkms No need to get a second account, I'll take care of it... yet then again... the more the merrier.

Comment: +100... Truly awesome!!

Comment: @JoeFrambach Thanks :) string parsing can be great fun!